# How to replace all nulls with dash in object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object and for all keys that have a null value I want to replace this null with an empty string (or a dash in my case)?

For example

```
Obj = {

key1: null,
key2: null,
key3: true,
...
key_n: null

}
```

Turns into

```
Obj = {

key1: "-",
key2: "-",
key3: true,
...
key_n: "-"

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions should show how you've tried to solve the problem yourself prior to asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```js
const Obj = {
  key1: null,
  key2: null,
  key3: true,

  key_n: null
};

for (const key in Obj) {
  const val = Obj[key];

  if (val === null) {
    Obj[key] = "-";
  }
}
console.log(Obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
  key1: null,
  key2: null,
  key3: true,
  key_n: null
};
Object
  .entries(obj)
  .forEach(function ([key, value]) {
    if (value === null) {

      this[key] = '-';
    }
  }, obj); // make use of `forEach`'s `thisArg` parameter.

console.log({ obj });
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to match whether a key's corresponding value is null or not , if yes then change it to **underscore**.

```js
Obj = {

    key1: null,
    key2: null,
    key3: true,
    key_n: null

    }

    Object.keys(Obj).map(key=>{
        if(!Obj[key])Obj[key] = "_"
    })
    console.log(Obj)
```

Comment: You should edit this code because right now you are checking `if (!Obj[key])` , this means even if a value is false, it will also convert it into "_"